# Toshiba Satellite C660, OpenGL 1.1, ATI Radeon Mobility HD 5470

Tags: opengl, driver, ati

How to update OpenGL 1.1 on Toshiba Satellite C660 with ATI Radeon Mobility HD 5470? The driver from Toshiba support doesn't include the OpenGL update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried many things finally figured out that it was the problem of Win8 and I've installed a fresh, stable Win7 and finally got OpenGL to v4.0. The reason I had to get this done was to start working with jMonkeyEngine3.

Answer (score 1):

Download the drivers from ATI/AMD directly. Go to this website http://support.amd.com/en-us/download

Enter the following values into the filter boxes:

1. Notebook Graphics
2. Radeon HD Series
3. Mobility Radeon HD 5xxx Series
4. `<Your Operating System>`

Then Click the "Display Results" button.

Comment: That would be to easy. I've tried that many times, but OpenGL doesn't get updated.

Comment: @esbej: How did you determine the OpenGL version? Did you look at the version info of the `opengl32.dll`? That version is fixed to 1.1, because that's the version for which the DLL interface has been formally specified. Anything beyond that happens at runtime. You need a OpenGL context then can use `glGetString(GL_VERSION)` to determine the OpenGL version actually supported by your system.

Comment: I've determined it by installing OpenGL Extensions Viewer. 
I tried many things finally figured out that it was the problem of  Win8 and I've installed a fresh, stable Win7 and finally got OpenGL to v4.0. The reason I had to get this done was to start working with jMonkeyEngine3. Thanks for your help! Now I mark this as a solved topic.